# ngx bootstrap modal not injecting properly

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use this 'BsModalService' to open a modal, but I'm getting the following error.

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
```

Here is My component.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, HostListener, OnInit, Inject, ElementRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { WINDOW } from "../providers/window.service";

import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  isCollapsed: boolean;
  magicHeight: number;
  invertNavBar: boolean = false;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  @ViewChild('navBar') navBarElementView: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('funcionalidades') funcionalidadeselementView: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    @Inject(WINDOW) private window

  ) {

  }
}
```

And here my module.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ModalPrincipalComponent} from '../components/modal_principal/modal_principal.component';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WINDOW_PROVIDERS } from "../providers/window.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalPrincipalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    CarouselModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [WINDOW_PROVIDERS],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

An interesting thing about this, is that if I add modalService as the last parameter in my constructor, I don't get this error, but the service still isn't injected, the variable value become undefined.

The library in general is working, I'm using carousel and collapse modules without any problem.

I've already tried to delete the node_modules folder and reinstall it, but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **`NgbModule`** and add it to imports

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still not working, I tried to use NgbModule.forRoot() and NgbModule in the imports array, but i'm still gettit the error.

Comment: No, still have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Well, actually, this time I tried to import the Router service, and i've got the same error, probably the problem is more complex.

Comment: lets discuss on chat

Comment: TS uses BsModalService so, no need to import NgbModule and ng-boostrap at all, BsModalService is from ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

try to add the static field into your AppComponent as follows

```
export class AppComponent {
...
static parameters = [BsModalService];

constructor(private modalService: BsModalService)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
```

you can write directly

```
 import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
```

the thing to solve this you need to do is 
in your **app.module.ts**

```
import { ModalModule, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

     imports: [
        ModalModule.forRoot()
   ],
     providers: [
        BsModalRef
   ],
```

I hope this will Help You.

Because it worked for me.